# After input hidden field has been added (appendTo), $_POST is empty on submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've looked at some of the similar posts on stack, but cannot find the answer nor solution. After append happens, I submit the form and var comes out to be empty. I checked html, after appending input field, it looks good:

```
<input type="hidden" name="imgdelete[]" value="5">
```

Please help, spent over 3 hours on this. Thank you

JQUERY

```
$('a.delete-img').bind('click',function()
{
    var imgid = $(this).attr('id');

    // add hidden field to let php know that this image was deleted
    $('<input>').attr({
        type: 'hidden',
        name: 'imgdelete[]',
        id: imgid,
        value: imgid
    }).prependTo('.tablepics tr:last');
});
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" id="editCarForm" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tablepics" id="id-form">
        {foreach from=$CARIMGS item=carimg}
        <tr class="car-row">
        <td id="{$carimg.imgid}">
            <a class="fancybox" href="../{$carimg.img}">
                <img width="{$THUMB_WIDTH}" alt=""  src="../{$carimg.thumb}"/></img>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td style="padding:5px" id="{$carimg.imgid}">
            <input type="text" id="imgorder" name="imgorder[{$carimg.imgid}]" value="{$carimg.order}" size="2" maxlength="2" />
            <br><br>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="{$carimg.imgid}" class="delete-img">delete</a><br>
        </td>
        </tr>
        {/foreach}      
        <tr>
        <br>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Images: </th>
            <td><input name="upload[]" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <td valign="top"> //this would be last one
                <input type="submit" value="" class="form-submit" />
                <input type="reset" value="" class="form-reset"  />
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: were is your `<form>` element?

Comment: I don't see a `<form>` ... how is anything being submitted?

Comment: Try changing `name: 'imgdelete[]',` to just `name: 'imgdelete',` since your form already contains `[]`

Comment: i tried, doesn't help. That was my first suspect. the other array works fine though

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's wrong, the `[]` has to be on every row.

Comment: You need to put this element into a `<td>`, not into the `<tr>`. The children of a `<tr>` must all be `<td>` or `<th>` elements.

Comment: Or you could put it in the `<form>`, outside the `<table>`.

Comment: @Barmar I meant in the jQuery, or were you referring to that also?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was referring to that. When using `[]`-style names, you have to use it consistently in every instance to get an array in PHP.

Comment: @Barmar Got it, and noted to file. I keep those handy. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('a.delete-img').bind('click',function()
{
    var imgid = $(this).attr('id');

    // add hidden field to let php know that this image was deleted
    $('<input>').attr({
        type: 'hidden',
        name: 'imgdelete[]',
        id: imgid,
        value: imgid
    }).prependTo('#editCarForm');
});
```

This inserts the hidden fields into the form outside the table. Your code was creating an invalid DOM, because you had `<input>` elements as direct children of `<tr>`, which is not permitted.

Comment: That worked, thank you. Didn't realize that DOM would brake. Learned something new.